# Imagen Hover alto automático

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, web

estoy creando en bootstrap una serie de imágenes que al hacer hover en ellas se cambian por la misma imagen pero en distinto color. En un principio lo había hecho con la etiqueta `<img>` y cambiando el contenido de la url por medio de css pero de este modo perdía ciertos atributos y no funcionaba.
Después o he intentado con background-image pero no me aparecen las imágenes al ser un div vacío, aunque le pusiera el atributo height: auto. Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de poner el alto automático para que sea responsive. Os dejo mi código.
Gracias.

```
 <section class="container-fluid cars-section">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mt-4" id="car-1"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mt-4" id="car-2"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mt-4" id="car-3"></div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mt-4" id="car-4"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mt-4" id="car-5"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mt-4" id="car-6"></div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mt-4" id="car-7"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mt-4" id="car-8"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mt-4" id="car-9"></div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mt-4" id="car-10"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mt-4" id="car-11"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mt-4" id="car-12"></div>
    <div class="row">

    </div>
</div>
```

```
#car-1{background: url("../img/cars/car1.jpg") no-repeat; background-size: cover; max-width: 100%; height:auto;}
#car-1:hover{background: url("../img/cars/car1.1.jpg") no-repeat; background-size: cover;}
#car-2{background: url("../img/cars/car2.jpg") no-repeat; background-size: cover;}
#car-2:hover{background: url("../img/cars/car2.2.jpg") no-repeat; background-size: cover;}
#car-3{background: url("../img/cars/car3.jpg") no-repeat; background-size: cover;}
#car-3:hover{background: url("../img/cars/car3.3.jpg") no-repeat; background-size: cover;}
```

Comment: Quizá te ayude: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13872/efecto-hover-con-im%C3%A1genes-y-texto?rq=1

Comment: Pero yo quiero cambiarlo por otra imagen no por un texto

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar algo así:
Con las propiedades background-size: cover; y background-position: center;

```
background-image: url(tuimagen.jpg);
display:block;
margin:auto;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;  
background-size: cover;      
background-position: center;
```

Espero y te sirva en algo.